# Creating a new table using data from two existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been struggling with this for the past few days and everything I do just doesn't seem to work. Any help would be very much appreciated. This is a homework question, but I've been racking my brain for 3 days now and my professor has been ZERO help.

What my dilemma is I'm trying to create a brand new table using Columns, and Rows from two existing tables.

Here is what the question looks like:

> Using the AP database, create a new table called 'Invoices2Qtr2012' that captures vendor and 
>   invoice data from the second quarter of 2012 for the following attributes in the invoices and
>   Vendors tables: VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, InvoiceDueDate, PaymentDate.
>
> In addition, include a new column that shows if each invoice payment was on time or late, and
>   another new column that shows which vendor had the largest invoice for each month. This
>   should only include data from the second quarter of 2012.

Here is the structure of the tables:

Invoices:

```
InvoiceId
VendorID
InvoiceNumber
InvoiceDate
InvoiceTotal
PaymentTotal
CreditTotal
TermsID
InvoiceDue
PaymentDate
```

Vendors:

```
VendorID
VendorName
VendorAddress1
VendorAddress2
VendorCity
VendorState
VendorZipCode
VendorPhone
VendorContactLName
VendorContactFName
DefaultTermsID
DefaultAccountNo
```

Here is what I have so far for my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices2Qtr2012 AS
SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, InvoiceDueDate, PaymentDate
FROM Invoices, Vendors
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2012-03-31' AND '2012-07-01'
```

Comment: What I find tricky about this question is the last part: a column that shows which vendor had the largest invoice for each month.  The table won't have single records for each vendor, so how do they want you to indicate that?  Do they want you to put something like a `LargestThisMonth` column and put a `True` in it only if that vendor-month record is the largest?

Comment: Typical homework question -- leave you to interpret the ambiguities.

Comment: @roryap that's what I'm assuming. I hate the ambiguity of this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it could be reduced to less statements and it may not work 100% but perhaps this can get you started or at least give you some idea:

```
CREATE TABLE Invoices2Qtr2012 AS
SELECT VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, InvoiceDueDate, PaymentDate, InvoiceDate
FROM Invoices, Vendors
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2012-03-31' AND '2012-07-01'

ALTER TABLE Invoices2Qtr2012
ADD LateOnTime varchar(255) DEFAULT 'On time'
ADD LargestInvoicePerMonth varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Not Largest'

UPDATE Invoices2Qtr2012
SET LateOnTime = 'Late'
WHERE PaymentDate > InvoiceDueDate;

UPDATE Invoices2Qtr2012
SET LargestInvoicePerMonth = 'Largest for April'
WHERE InvoiceTotal >= ALL (SELECT InvoiceTotal FROM Invoices2Qtr2012 WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2012-03-31' AND '2012-05-01')

UPDATE Invoices2Qtr2012
SET LargestInvoicePerMonth = 'Largest for May'
WHERE InvoiceTotal >= ALL (SELECT InvoiceTotal FROM Invoices2Qtr2012 WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2012-04-31' AND '2012-06-01')

UPDATE Invoices2Qtr2012
SET LargestInvoicePerMonth = 'Largest for June'
WHERE InvoiceTotal >= ALL (SELECT InvoiceTotal FROM Invoices2Qtr2012 WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2012-05-31' AND '2012-07-01')
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT INTO statement will create the table for you. So your code will be:

```
SELECT INTO Invoices2Qtr2012  VendorName, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTotal, InvoiceDueDate, PaymentDate
FROM Invoices, Vendors
WHERE InvoiceDate BETWEEN '2012-03-31' AND '2012-07-01'
```

After this I suggest to create appropriate indexes, keys and constraints.

Table Invoices2Qtr2012 must not exists.

Comment: Where are the additional columns?  "In addition, include a new column that shows if each invoice payment was on time or late, and another new column that shows which vendor had the largest invoice for each month. This should only include data from the second quarter of 2012."

Comment: From question it seems to be a problem creating table. For this my answer.